# finding nodes at depth N in a tree with racket

Tags: recursion, lisp, binary-tree, racket

I've written a piece of code which returns the nodes which are at depth N of a tree. The root is considered to be at depth 1.

```
#lang racket

(define (depth n tree) (
                    cond [(= n 1) (car tree)]
                         [(> n 1) (
                                   cond [(and (null? (cadr tree)) (null? (caddr tree)))
                                         (null)]
          
                                        [(and (not (null? (cadr tree))) (null? (caddr tree))) 
                                         (cons (depth (- n 1) (cadr tree)) null)]
         
                                        [(and (null? (cadr tree)) (not (null? (caddr tree)))) 
                                         (cons (depth (- n 1) (caddr tree)) null)]
         
                                        [(and (not (null? (cadr tree))) (not (null? (caddr tree))))
                                         (cons (depth (- n 1) (cadr tree)) (depth (- n 1) (caddr tree)))]
                                        )]
                         )
  )
```

Which works fine for depth 1, 2 and 3.

```
(define sampleTree
  `(A 
    (B 
     (D () ())
     (E () ())
     )
    (C
     ()
     (F
      (G () ())
      ()
      )
     )
    )
  )

(depth 1 sampleTree)
(depth 2 sampleTree)
(depth 3 sampleTree)
```

gives

```
'A
'(B . C)
'((D . E) F)
```

But for some reason, this does not work for depth 4.

```
(depth 4 sampleTree)
 application: not a procedure;
  expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '()
```

I honestly have no idea why this happens. It seems like the `null` in the first branch of `> n 1` is getting applied to something.

Any help on debugging this code is appreciated.

Comment: Consistent indentation and more standard formatting would make that a lot easier to read. If you're using DrRacket, it has a Reindent All command in the Racket menu that can help.

Comment: What is `null` in Racket? Is it a function? What happens when you try to call a non-function like it was a function?

Comment: Sorry for the indentation, fixed it according to DrRacket. I thought `null` is how I can return an empty list, I didn't mean to call it as a function. But I understand now, Thank you very much!

Comment: That reformatting isn't quite what I'd hoped for. It doesn't handle the opening paren being on a different line from the first element of the s-expr very well, I guess. Peter's answer has a more typical formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `(null)`. `null` is bound to the value `'()`. Putting parentheses around it tries to apply it as a procedure.

```
> null
'()
> (null)
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '()
 [,bt for context]
```

---

May I suggest the following code formatting:

```lisp
(define (depth n tree)
  (cond
   [(= n 1) (car tree)]
   [(> n 1)
    (cond
     [(and (null? (cadr tree)) (null? (caddr tree))) '()]
     [(and (not (null? (cadr tree))) (null? (caddr tree)))
      (cons (depth (- n 1) (cadr tree)) null)]
     [(and (null? (cadr tree)) (not (null? (caddr tree))))
      (cons (depth (- n 1) (caddr tree)) null)]
     [(and (not (null? (cadr tree))) (not (null? (caddr tree))))
      (cons (depth (- n 1) (cadr tree)) (depth (- n 1) (caddr tree)))])]))
```

---

You may also want to ask yourself what type of value `depth` should return. In your example output, `'A` is a symbol, `'(B . C)` is a pair, and `'((D . E) F)` is a proper list (with a pair as the first element).

Answer (score 2):

As Peter pointed out, your result, with all the improper pairs, is probably not what you want - a proper list of values makes more sense. Here's a version that gives that, by using `list` and `append` instead of `cons`:

```lisp
#lang racket/base
(require racket/list) ; For first, second, etc.

;;; Use functions to access parts of the tree structure to be clearer about what's being looked at
;;; and to make it easier to change to a struct or other more efficient implementation.
(define (node-value node)
  (first node))
(define (node-left-child node)
  (second node))
(define (node-right-child node)
  (third node))

(define (depth desired-depth head)
  (cond
    ((= desired-depth 1)
     (list (node-value head)))
    ((> desired-depth 1)
     (append (if (null? (node-left-child head))  '() (depth (- desired-depth 1) (node-left-child head)))
             (if (null? (node-right-child head)) '() (depth (- desired-depth 1) (node-right-child head)))))))

(define sampleTree
  '(A 
    (B 
     (D () ())
     (E () ()))
    (C
     ()
     (F
      (G () ())
      ()))))

(depth 1 sampleTree) ; '(A)
(depth 2 sampleTree) ; '(B C)
(depth 3 sampleTree) ; '(D E F)
(depth 4 sampleTree) ; '(G)
```